# USB input freezes on windows but not Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have a USB-Hub attached to a computer via a 4m USB 3.0 extension cord (I know ...), and Keyboard and mouse are on this hub. The symptom is that occasionally, mouse and keyboard freeze and unfreeze after a few seconds; the keyboard often emits 40 copies of the last typed character, the mouse jumps into the direction it was traveling.

- This happens about once every 20-30 seconds.
- When removing extension cable and plugging in directly, the problem disappears
- When the keyboard or mouse are used continuously, the problem also disappears; only when the devices are idle for a bit
- The problem seems either nonexistent or much less pronouncesd on my elementaryOS Linux
- An active USB cable did not show any improvement

How can I find out the root cause of this?

Comment: When it only happens if USB is idle and only on Windows then the chance is high that some device power-saving feature may be involved. You can try to disable energy saving for the keyboard/mouse/USB hub in device manager.

Comment: I should have added that I scoured all power settings for power-related options, but nothing was enabled that seemed related.

Comment: Sounds like a communication issue due to the length of the USB extension, else it's a bad extension - test with a known-good extension of the same length and if the issue still occurs, the length is likely an issue. _(If either is the issue, it's likely Windows and Linux have different standards for the voltage/amperage loss that occurs)_.

Comment: @oarfish All USB devices have the option to use energy saving features in Windows device manager (enabled by default).

Comment: Yes, those are disabled. @JW0914, I guess this hypothesis fits the data, but still strange that an active usb cable doesn't help here.